# Send data to a HTML page using block content

Tags: python, django

I have code written in python django to parse a url and send the tag data to another html page, so I have coded in views.py and I need to send data to html page using block content.

Code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import urllib  
import re 

def home(request):
    htmlf = urllib.urlopen("https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls") 
    htmlt = htmlf.read() 
    regex = '<title>(.+?)</title> ' 
    patt = re.compile(regex) 
    price = re.findall(patt,htmlt) 
    return render_to_response("home.html", {'hello': price} )
```

home.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to story time!<h1>
    {% block content %}
    {{hello}}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

the problem here is I need to print the content of price in the home.html page.

Comment: This is exactly what your code is doing, so what is the problem with it?

Comment: You need `context_instance = RequestContext(request)` for the variables to get printed

Comment: SO can u please give details how to use that please

Comment: I need to print the value of price in  my html page thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using **Django 1.4+** Get rid of long `render_to_response`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    htmlf = urllib.urlopen("https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls") 
    htmlt = htmlf.read() 
    regex = '<title>(.+?)</title> ' 
    patt = re.compile(regex) 
    price = re.findall(patt,htmlt) 
    return render(request, "home.html", {'hello': price} )
```

Comment: ya i am using django 1.5

Comment: thats also not working,,, it just printing [],, it should print values inside this []

Comment: Put only `return render(request, "home.html", {'hello': price})`, if it's not working your context variable might be empty. Try with `return render(request, "home.html", {'hello': 'price'})` and see if it's price or not.

Comment: the value of price should be in utfencoding format??  i used BeutifulSoup so it working,,,                                                        from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

def home(request):
    url = urllib.urlopen("http://pruthvipraveen.bugs3.com")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url) 
 #soup.body.name
 #soup.body.string
    #soup.get_text()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'hello':soup.p.string} )